# Firefox Snap Segmentation Fault Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 22.04, snap

I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to run the Firefox snap Kubuntu 22.04. This is not a new install, and I have been running Kubuntu 22.04 since it was released.

When attempting to find a solution a few days ago, I was getting this error:

```
/bin/bash: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: unsupported version 0 of Verdef record
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: unsupported version 0 of Verneed record
```

I wasn't able to find a great deal of info. And when I came back to the problem today, I started getting a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

I tried to refresh the snap and got this message:

```
$ snap refresh firefox
error: cannot perform the following tasks: - Run post-refresh hook of "firefox" snap if present (run hook "post-refresh": signal: segmentation fault (core dumped))
```

Comment: A workaround is to remove the snap version and install the apt version of Firefox from the Mozilla PPA

Comment: Try `sudo snap revert firefox` to downgrade back to the previous working version. then try the refresh again.

Comment: I have the same error message: /bin/bash: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: unsupported version 0 of Verdef record. I reboot computer and firefox works again. And I have the last snap version. Refresh is working on my computer. Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: Thank you @Mahler, rebooting my computer did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the snap version did not work. Reverting it did not work either. However, a simple reboot seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: I returned to 5.17 kernel from 6.0, and no need to reboot. The problem disappeared.